# Game and browse internet on Sony Internet TV and Google TV?

Tags: google-tv

I was wondering if it was possible to use the "Dual-View" or whatever Google and Sony label their function to allow a user to watch TV and browse the web at the same time, with gaming.

Like say, browsing the web, and playing the 360.  Or something along those lines.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: From everything that I have read, it will be quite possible.  I know it will work with DTV and analog TV but am unsure with HDMI, component or other connectors.

Comment: Thanks, btw, this might need a separate question, but do you know if it's possible to use GTV without Cable?  Just an Internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I called Sony Support, and although they seemed somewhat unconfident, I found two different people who confirmed the use of Dual-View with any HDMI component.

In other words, if you have a 360 with an HDMI connection, and you have it plugged into your Sony Internet TV, you can use the Dual-View between your actual television signal and your game on the 360.  Same thing with a computer with an HDMI output and any other console like the PS3.

Sounds great to me! :)